# Find 2 unknowns in a symmetric matrix given the eigenvector.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find A and B in the symmetric matrix with the given eigenvector below.

New to eigenvector algebra. Read some sections in Schaum Linear Algebra but still cannot figure it out on how to approach this question. Hope some tips on how to get me going. Thanks.

[image: the symmetric matrix and the eigenvector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

If the matrix is $M$, and the eigenvector is $v$, then write down the equation $$Mv=\lambda v$$

It forms a system of equations. Can you write them down?

Comment: Let me try 10x-2y+8z=1  -2x+14y+Az=0  8x+Ay+Bz=1

Comment: @Plumberms What you wrote makes no sense. Where the heck did you get $x,y$ and $z$? What in this equation represents $Mv$, and what represents $\lambda v$?

Comment: @Plumberms Write down $Mv$. Write down $\lambda v$. Then, write down the first component of $Mv$, and the first component of $\lambda v$. That gives you the first equation. Do the same for the second and third component.

Comment: Sorry, very new to this. Appreciate showing the first equation and hopefully that will be my aha moment. Thanks.

Comment: @Plumberms Write down what $Mv$ is equal to.

Comment: @Plumberms I understand you're new to this, but me solving it for you won't do any of us any good. I can guide you, but I will guide you with *questions*, not answers. Now, you know what a matrix is, and since you are already at the topic of *eigenvectors*, you must have at least some experience in multiplying a matrix and a vector. Now you know what $M$ is, and you know what $v$ is, so just multiply them together to get a vector $Mv$ and write it down.

Comment: Many thanks. Appreciate your guidance. Yes, best way to learn is to actually do it and not just getting the answer from others. Pardon me for not using the right format here. My attempt as follows. 6.1+-1.0+3.1   -1.0+7.0+A.1  3.1+A.0+B.1  giving  9    A-1    B+3   Need help on A-1=?  B+3=? Thanks.

Comment: Used wrong numbers! Should be 10.1+-2.0+8.1  -2.1+14.0+A.1  8.1+A.0+B.1  giving  18  A-2  B+8.

Comment: @Plumberms Exactly, $Mv=[18,A-2, B+8]$ (it's better to write it with commas so you separate the three variables). Now, what is $\lambda\cdot v$ equal to?

Comment: I think [lamda, 0, lamda] with lamda =18, A=2, B=10. Same as what @Fred has stated. Took me too long to figure this out! But it will stay in my mind now. Thanks for your help. And thanks Fred too.

Comment: @Plumberms **Yes**! Correct! Well done!

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the matrix and $b$ the eigenvector then we get

$Ab=(18, A-2,B+8)^T$. Since $Ab=\lambda b$ for some scalar $ \lambda$, we see:

$A-2=0$ , $18= \lambda$ and $B+8=\lambda$.

Conclusion: $A=2, B=10$ and $ \lambda =18$.

Comment: Took me some time to figure this out. Taking baby steps in eigen subject. Now what you said is clearer. Appreciate your help.